# Meteor Hybrid mobile app connected to platform

Tags: cordova, meteor

the project consists on a meteor mobile app connected to a web platform , so the all the publication will be in the platform , and all the data .
my question is regarding the architecture of the project , i guess there's no need to make json end points since the mobile is in meteor as well .
but how the project will be organised ?
will the mobile app be like a subproject of the web Platform ? how can i subscribe to the remote Platform publications ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you asking. If you try to do two separate applications (mobile + web) connected to the same database and share the same publications etc. it is possible with manually connecting one application to the other DDP server.

The best option would be to connect mobile app, since it is client only to the web application's DPP server using [DDP.connect](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddp_connect)` and probably a good option would be also to disable the autoupdate in the mobile app, since after connecting to web app ddp server, it's gonna return web app's version and not mobile's.